# Checking a checkbox node programmatically with jsTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

In a tree built with jsTree, I have the text within the `<a>` tag sitting in a variable. I would like to **check** that node. How can I do so?

I am currently finding that node, using jQuery, and altering its class. However, this does not repair the parent node by making the parent **undetermined** in its class. I tried doing `$('.colors').jstree("checkbox_repair")`, but that didn't seem to do anything.

It would be great if someone could actually answer both those questions, since they are related to the same problem.

Here is a jsFiddle, illustrating the issue--> http://jsfiddle.net/thapar/5XAjU/

Comment: put the code here: http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In js_tree there are `.check_node ( node )` and `.uncheck_node ( node )` functions, i think this is what you are asking for.  Soe the documentation here: http://www.jstree.com/documentation/checkbox

This is an excerpt from the documentation in the link above, "how to perform an operation":

```
/* METHOD ONE */
jQuery("some-selector-to-container-node-here")
    .jstree("operation_name" [, argument_1, argument_2, ...]);

/* METHOD TWO */
jQuery.jstree._reference(needle)
    /* NEEDLE can be a DOM node or selector for the container or a node within the container */
    .operation_name([ argument_1, argument_2, ...]);
```

So I think this syntax should work

```
$.jstree._reference(".colors").check_node('li#tree_3');
```

Also i am not sure you should be using a class to reference your tree.  Probably use an ID to reference your tree, and then use this syntax:

```
$.jstree._reference("#colors").check_node('li#tree_3');
```

//EDIT: Please keep in mind that the newest version of jsTree doesn't have a function called _reference anymore. It got renamed to reference (without the leading underscore). (Last checked 24/08/2015 15:45 by @mkli90)
Link: https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.reference(needle)

Comment: I've seen that jeffery_the_wind, however, that's not very clear on usage. Can you provide an example? For example, this **does not** work: $('.colors').check_node('li#tree_3'), where tree_3 is a unique identifier for that node. >>>TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'check_node'.

Comment: @Raj ~ OK I checked the documentation and edited the answer.  I suggest you take some time and thoroughly read through the documentation, I think it will benefit you a lot.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind how to check multiple nodes, I assume `$.jstree._reference("#colors").check_node('#tree_3','#tree_4');`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check jsTree nodes on load for example like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.jstree._reference('#menu').check_node('#pih2');
});
```

it does not work. For me works following:

```
$(function () {
    $('#mainMenu1').bind('loaded.jstree', function(e, data){ //waiting for loading
          $.jstree._reference('#menu').check_node('#pih2');  //check node with id pih2
        $.jstree._reference('#menu').check_node('#pih6');  //check node with id pih6
  }); 
});
```

I use jsTree 1.0-rc3 and JQuery 1.7.1.
Aloe

Answer (score 2):

In current versions of jstree the following syntax works:

```
$("#my_tree").jstree("check_node", node_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add this solution, the `select_node` function does the same function as `check_node`. we can use it as follows;

```js
$('#jstree_id').on('loaded.jstree', function() {
    $("#jstree_id").jstree("select_node", ["list of nodes go here"]);
});
```

You can use it to select multiple nodes in an array or a single node.